# How to check variables on a certain date +/- 2 days in R

Tags: r

I really hope someone can help me with this question, because I've been struggling for some time. My data looks like this:

```
ID DATE        VAR1       VAR2  
01 2018-07-27      0         0  
01 2018-07-28      0         0  
01 2018-07-29      0         1  
01 2018-07-30      0         1  
01 2018-07-31      0         1  
01 2018-08-01      0         0
02 2018-09-30      1         0  
02 2018-10-01      0         0  
02 2018-10-02      0         1  
02 2018-10-03      1         1  
02 2018-10-04      1         1  
02 2018-10-05      0         1  
02 2018-10-06      0         0  
02 2018-10-07      0         0  
02 2018-10-08      0         0  
02 2018-10-10      0         0  
02 2018-10-12      0         0  
02 2018-10-13      0         0 
02 2018-10-14      0         0  
02 2018-10-15      1         0  
02 2018-10-18      1         0  
02 2018-10-19      0         0  
02 2018-10-20      0         0 
02 2018-10-26      0         0  
02 2018-10-28      0         0  
02 2018-11-02      0         1
```

I want to know for each ID if VAR1 was present or not on the first day VAR 2 was present +/- 2 days. I would like to store the answers in a new dataframe, like this:

```
ID PRESENT
01 0  
02 1
```

Does someone know how to do this? VAR2 is the menstrual cycle. For some ID's I have data of multiple menstruations. If VAR1 was present on the first day +/- 2 days in one of the menstruations, I want them to come out positive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer would seem to be no for all six rows which you showed us.  Can you include other sample data which has matches, and also include the expected output?

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of going about it, but there should be a better hack:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    DATE = as.Date(DATE),
    VAR2 = ifelse(VAR2 == 1 & lag(VAR2) == 1, 0, VAR2),
    PRESENT = sapply(DATE,
                     function(x) any(VAR1[between(DATE, x - 2, x + 2)] == 1)) & VAR2 == 1
  ) %>% 
  summarise(PRESENT = +any(PRESENT))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID PRESENT
  <int>   <int>
1     1       0
2     2       1
```

Data used:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), DATE = structure(1:26, .Label = c("2018-07-27", "2018-07-28", 
"2018-07-29", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-09-30", 
"2018-10-01", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "2018-10-05", 
"2018-10-06", "2018-10-07", "2018-10-08", "2018-10-10", "2018-10-12", 
"2018-10-13", "2018-10-14", "2018-10-15", "2018-10-18", "2018-10-19", 
"2018-10-20", "2018-10-26", "2018-10-28", "2018-11-02"), class = "factor"), 
    VAR1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    VAR2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts! Unfortunately this gives the following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Expecting a single value: [extent=114]..

Comment: Not sure. 1) Can you try with my latest edit? 2) Do you have duplicate dates? 3) Your data seems to be more complex; can you share more of it? You can do it via `dput(yourdf)`

Comment: Yes, it's probably because I have multiple menstruations in my dataset. In the data shown I've only showed one period for ID 2, but there are some patients for whom I have data of more than one period. My dataset is too big to use dput, but I will add some more data to my question.

Comment: I now added more data for ID 2. There's now a second menstruation (VAR2). During this menstruation VAR1 is absent. I still want ID 2 to come out positive, because VAR1 was present during one episode of VAR2. Do you understand my question?

Comment: I've changed it now, it runs on your example. Not sure why you're getting the error - perhaps you need to update your `dplyr` version, or data is more complex.

Comment: Hm, I've updated dplyr, but it still doesn't seem to work. Maybe the problem is that VAR1 can be present on multiple days during VAR2? I've updated this in my example data. Does the code still work with you?

Comment: Still runs for me. I've posted my `dput` of your data. If you copy paste it and if it runs for you, then it means your data is more complex, something's missing from example; if it doesn't run on my `dput`, then something with `dplyr` is wrong.

Comment: Very weird. The code doesn't run on your dput either. I updated the dplyr package, R and Rstudio, but it still won't work. Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: It was my mistake - I made a typo with the `between` argument, and apparently it worked when I had `data.table` loaded as well. I've corrected it now and it should run also only with `dplyr` (have checked it), apologies